# Creating a Unity Lens: The name `Activation' does not exist in the context of `Unity'

Tags: unity, application-development, lenses, vala

I'm trying to create a Lens for Unity in 11.10 using vala. This is my daemon.vala:

```
using Dee;
using Gee;

namespace PidginLens
{
    public class Daemon : GLib.Object, Unity.Activation
    {
        public static void main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now trying to compiling with `valac --pkg gee-1.0 --pkg dee-1.0 --pkg unity` just says

```
daemon.vala:6.40-6.55: error: The type name `Unity.Activation' could not be found
public class Daemon : GLib.Object, Unity.Activation
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

libunity4 libunity6 libunity-dev libunity-core-4.0.4 libunity-core-4.0-dev gir1.2-unity-4.0 are all installed, and it obviously finds the unity package (since changing `--pkg unity` to something like `--pkg unity-not-here` yields another error.
So what's my mistake? why is Unity.Activation not there?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you provide a pointer to the documentation of Unity.Activation? I can only find [Unity.ActivationResponse](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses)...

Comment: So did i, i checked unity.vala on my machine and the only hit i found for 'Activation' was ActivationResponse.
I followed the example at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses which brought me to my current problem. :(

Comment: Are you trying this on Oneiric (Unity 4) or Precise (Unity 5)?  The API has changed slightly.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) x64

Answer (score 5):

The Unity.Activation interface was dropped as of Unity 4 (Ubuntu 11.10).  Instead you can hook into the activation callback using signals like this:

```
scope.activate_uri.connect(on_uri_activated);
```

If you are not overriding the activation handling, you probably only need remove Unity.Activation and recompile.

Full documentation for Unity 4 (Ubuntu 11.10) can be viewed here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/c/Unity-4.0.html